# Find the length of $AD$ in the parallelogram.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

**Problem:** In the parallelogram $ABCD, \quad \measuredangle DBC=45^{\text{o}}, \quad\measuredangle BDC=30^{\text{o}}$ and $|AB|=5\sqrt{2}$. Find the length of $AD.$

I drew this:

[image]

Is this interpretation correct? I know that $\measuredangle BAD=\measuredangle BCD=105^{\text{o}},$ using the law of cosines I get

$$|BD|^2=x^2+(5\sqrt{2})^2-10x\sqrt{2}\cos{105^{\text{o}}}.$$

I also know that $\measuredangle ABD=30^{\text{o}},$ so now I can apply law of cosines again on $\triangle ABD$ with sides $BD, \quad 5\sqrt{2}$ and the angle between the two sides $30^{\text{o}}.$ So:

$$x^2=|BD|^2+(5\sqrt{2})^2-10|BD|\sqrt{2}\cos{30^{\text{o}}},$$

but this is a polynomial of the 4th degree with only complex solutions. I'm probably making it a lot harder than it is. Any tips?

Comment: Or you can apply the law of sines once.

Comment: @KennyLau - How?

Comment: See my answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\dfrac{AD}{\sin \angle ABD} &=& \dfrac{AB}{\sin \angle ADB} \\
\dfrac{x}{\sin 30^\circ} &=& \dfrac{5\sqrt2}{\sin 45^\circ} \\
2x &=& 10 \\
x &=& 5 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Embarrasingly easy. Ofcourse, thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I thought I already did.

Comment: @Parseval thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $AD=BC$ and $AB=CD$

$CD/\text{sin}45^\circ=x/\text{sin}30^\circ$

Answer (score 1):

Let $CE$ be an altitude of $\Delta DEC$.

Thus, since $\measuredangle EDC=30^{\circ}$, we obtain
$$EC=\frac{1}{2}\cdot5\sqrt2=\frac{5}{\sqrt2}$$ and since $\measuredangle DBC=45^{\circ}$, we obtain:
$$BC=EC\cdot\sqrt2=5.$$
Done!